# Spacing is varying between two mdframed environments with llncs class

Tags: spacing

Try out the MWE below. If I uncomment the commented line and comment out the previous one, the space between two `mdframed' environments increases drastically.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[linecolor=gray!50,backgroundcolor=gray!25,roundcorner=.25em]{darkgraybox}
\newmdenv[linecolor=gray!50,backgroundcolor=gray!10,roundcorner=.25em]{lightgraybox}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum*[1]
    %\lipsum*[1-2]

    \vspace*{2mm}
    \begin{darkgraybox}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{darkgraybox}

    \vspace*{2mm}
    \begin{lightgraybox}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{lightgraybox}

    \vspace*{2mm}
    \begin{darkgraybox}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{darkgraybox}

    \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have the `llncs.cls` class file but it seems to me that this is just caused by the page breaks fitting around the frames combined with your `\vspace` command